# How long can I store the data on the flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery

how long can I store the data on the flash drive safely, without connecting it to a computer or any other host?

**Edit**

I understand that flash pens are absolutely not suitable for backup and storage. My question is the issue of data recovery. That's why it's tagged accordingly. [Another question](https://superuser.com/questions/297890) have in mind the use of the stick from time to time.
In other words, do I have a chance to find the data corrupted if I haven't used the drive for a long time?

Comment: this is still a matter of ongoing research. See this article, which cites a dell report that indicates that it could be as little as 3 months in worst cases: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/hard-drives-ssds-flash-drives-how-long-will-your-storage-media-last/ but newer indications contradict that. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2925173/debunked-your-ssd-wont-lose-data-if-left-unplugged-after-all.html

Comment: Exact same question here: 
http://superuser.com/questions/297890/how-long-can-you-read-files-from-a-flash-drive-if-kept-in-a-cool-dark-room

Comment: That isn't exactly the same and it doesn't answer the Op's question.

Answer (score 2):

Most manufacturers seem to claim a 10 year lifespan.

However, the biggest problem with them is that they degrade with use, especially with writing. They are also relatively fragile when in use and are fairly easily corrupted.

In my experience you should never rely on them for archival storage.

Some references for storage life:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_permanence
- http://www.allmemorycards.com/glossary/reliability.htm
- http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/portablefilestorage/gr/swivelproflash.htm
- http://forum.corsair.com/v2/showthread.php?t=72882

Clearly the manufacturers are very cagey about quoting figures.

Comment: He's asking about data retention. Do flash drive manufacturers really claim a 10 year data retention period without the drives being powered on in all that time?

Comment: @Karan Exactly about it, not storage. How can it be dup?

Comment: I'd love to see an independent study confirming the 10 year data retention claim. The wiki link has nothing relevant, nor does the Corsair forum thread provide an official response. The AllMemoryCards link states, "*Under normal circumstances and normal use* the data retention time for a memory card is at least 10 years." This is weasel wording according to me. Where's the proof from any manufacturer that non-powered drives can retain their data for 10 years or more? Probably they'll just say that this is not normal use...

Comment: @Karan, you are making far too much of my comments. Not sure why. I made it clear that this is a claim not a fact. I also made it clear that this should not be relied on. Please be a little less aggressive when responding, it is frustrating.

Comment: @JulianKnight: My first comment was directed towards you and you updated your answer accordingly. My second comment as anyone can see was a mini rant directed towards manufacturers. Nowhere did I ask *you* to provide proof; that wasn't my intent at all. I also clearly didn't mean that you were the one using weasel words.