# How to recover deleted files on Windows?

Tags: windows-8.1, file-recovery

I have Windows 8.1 build 9600 and I have 2 disk partitions. Windows is installed on one partition, while I use for the second one backing up data. I have deleted some data from second partition (the one where Windows is not installed) and now I can't find it in Recycle Bin or anywhere on computer. Is this file permanently deleted from disk or can I restore it somehow? This file is really important to me.

Answer (score 5):

You should **stop using that partition** until your data is recovered. The file may still be there, but it's ready to be overwritten. Every time the system writes to that partition it may overwrite a part of your file, so stop using it for now.

Then download and install some data recovery software. [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) is good, you can give it a try. Remember to download and install to your first partition. Then run Recuva (or another file recovery utility) and let it do its job. If you're lucky, you'll get your file back.

Then buy an external drive and start making regular backups. For very important data use [3-2-1 method](https://superuser.com/a/294170/194694).

Answer (score 0):

You can use some data recovery softwares (these are avilable as free and paid versions). Whether you have deleted the data by (Shift+Del) or by emptying your recycle bin certain softwares might be able to recover them. Also if the files are merely deleted just now, use the softwares after some time (like tomorrow) for being sure that the data recovers as freshly deleted data is less probably recovorable. Here you can use [Easeus](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/).